# How can I continue a snakemake workflow from a subset of files created at some point in the workflow? (tried checkpoint)

Tags: snakemake

At some point in my workflow, I'm selecting a subset of files. I want to use that subset of files to continue with the next steps in my workflow:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        "results/selected_files.tsv",

checkpoint select_by_size:
    input:
        "results/selected_seqs"
    output:
        directory("results/selected_seqs_by_size")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir -p {output[0]} 
        # The second -size is only for testing, remove it for a real run
        find {input} -size +302c -size -304c -exec cp {{}} {output[0]} \;
        """

def get_selected_files(wildcards):
    ck_output = checkpoints.select_by_size.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    GENES,  = glob_wildcards(join(ck_output, "{gene}.fasta"))
    return expand(join(ck_output, "{GENE}.fasta"), GENE=GENES)

rule create_table_sel:
    input:
        get_selected_files
    output:
        "results/selected_files.tsv"
    run:
        with open(output[0], 'w') as fh:
            for f in input:
               print(Path(f).stem, f, file=fh, sep='\t')
```

The rule `create_table_sel` creates a table that look like this:

```
JLEOKLFN_00589  results/selected_seqs_by_size/JLEOKLFN_00589.fasta
JLEOKLFN_01812  results/selected_seqs_by_size/JLEOKLFN_01812.fasta
```

If I try to use this table to get single files into a following rule, it fails (adding `"results/a3ms.txt"` to `rule all`)

```py
def get_seqs(wildcards):
    df = pd.read_csv("results/selected_files.tsv", sep="\t", header=None, index_col=0)
    return df.loc[wildcards.gene].values[0]

rule hhblits_msa:
    input:
        get_seqs
        # "results/selected_seqs_by_size/{gene}.fasta"
    output:
        "results/hhblits_msa/{gene}.a3m"
    log:
        "logs/hhblits/{gene}_msa.log" 
    params:
        db=config["msa_db"],
        n_iter= 2
    threads: 4
    shell:
        """
        mkdir -p results/hhblits_msa
        hhblits -i {input[0]} -d {params.db} -oa3m {output[0]} -cpu {threads}  -n {params.n_iter} \
        &> {log}
        """

# The intention is to use the above rule as input
rule agg:
    input:
        "results/hhblits_msa/{gene}.a3m"
    output:
        "results/a3ms.txt"
    shell:
        "echo {input} >> {output}"
```

```sh
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'gene'
```

If I use something like `snakemake --cores 4 results/hhblits_msa/JLEOKLFN_00589.a3m`, it runs without problems, but of course I want to use this workflow without the need to specify an output file in the command line.

How can I add the rule `hhblits_msa` to my workflow? How can I continue any workflow from a subset of files created at some point in the same workflow?

Also, someway related, is it possible to use the `checkpoints` object to return a single file and not only return all the files with `expand`? I tried a few thigs and I fails because the is no way to get the wildcards. The idea would be to use that single file as input of any rule, like `hhblits_msa`.

**ADDED**

The problem is to use the files created in `select_by_size` as input to `hhblits_msa`. Given that those files are created in the same workflow, and I don't know them beforehand, I cannot include them in `all`. When I use this workflow or the one suggested by [Jianyu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70371059/4020215), the rule `hhblits_msa` doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit unsure about your workflow design, but I feel like you don't need `create_table_sel` rule.

You might want to move your input function to rule `agg`, also modifies the input function to return the expected input for `agg`, an example:

```
def get_selected_files(wildcards):
    ck_output = checkpoints.select_by_size.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    GENES,  = glob_wildcards(join(ck_output, "{gene}.fasta"))
    return expand("results/hhblits_msa/{GENE}.a3m", GENE=GENES)
```

Then in accordance to this change, your `hhblits_msa` rule should look like:

```
rule hhblits_msa:
    input:
        "results/selected_seqs_by_size/{gene}.fasta"
    output:
        "results/hhblits_msa/{gene}.a3m"
    ... # log, parameters and shell command
```

The procedure of snakemake execution would be like:

1.`agg` -> 2.input function `get_selected_files` -> 3.execute checkpoint -> 4. execute `hhblits_msa` -> execute `agg`

Comment: If i make these changes, and delete `get_seqs` and `create_table_sel` I got `select_by_size` --> `agg` --> `all`, **but no `hhblits` executed**. The problem is to include the files produced by `select_by_size` into `all`, but given that those files are produced in the same workflow, i cannot include them in `all`. That's why I was trying to create a table and use that as input to `hhblits`.

Comment: That sounds weird, because I changed the input of `agg` to be the output of `hhblits_msa`, it should know that it needs to run `hhblits_msa` after checkpoint rule got executed. Did you actually run the pipeline or only the dry-run? Because in dry-run you won't see the `hhblits_msa` in the workflow but it would be included if you ran the pipeline

Comment: I was producing the "rulegraph", so it should count as a dry-run. I thought snakemake would acknowledge all the rules to be run but i guess cannot know at that point. I ran it and it worked. Thanks!